# $\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ range is $[-1,1]$, when $|z|=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The range of

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right), \quad z \in \mathbb{C}$$

should be $[-1,1]$, 
when $|z|=1$?

Any idea how to see it?

---

I tried de Moivre (since it has the $|z|$ term), but it doesn't seem to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z\in\mathbb C$ and $|z|=1$ then $z=e^{it}$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$.

$$
z + \frac 1 z = e^{it} + e^{-it} = 2\cos t.
$$
Can you do the rest?